# New.....answer-a-thon! First for 2012!

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, answers

So another year, and we have our fantastic 100% answered questions flagging a bit recently.

We have two ways of handling this:

1) Answering them. Of course ;)

2) Putting bounties on them and hoping that'll help.

Number 1 is obviously preferable, and amazingly, putting a bounty on one of the several Georgia ones actually elicited some responses recently.  However, we're still down to 99% again, so it's time to bring out the heavy hitting in the form of an answerathon!

So if you want to join in socially, join the chat room as per [the schedule](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule).

at 9am UTC, for the social side.  But if you can't make it, never fear, answer a question or three anyway!

Tell all your friends, and register as well - it only takes two clicks, even if you can't make it on the day, it helps if you're there in spirit, for those slogging it out on the harder questions to source answers for!